# Geometry Nodes: Orientation of instances of instances on curve circle

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this issue that half of the instances on the sphere are inverted:

[image]

How to get them like so and still keep their individual rotation intact? Ah, and important is to have all the individual instances connected last, so that I can run a Geometry Proximity through these, so that they open and close in different times like flower petals opening.

[image]

It's okay if we just point them to the origin of the sphere, but even more fantastic would be to have these function even on a capsule or any surface for that matter.

Nodes:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yay! Got an answer from [higgas](https://twitter.com/higgsasxyz/status/1677421561341435906?s=20) in Twitter:

[image]